# Tikz knots package: line style with consider self-intersections

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots

Using the tikz `knots` package, when using the option `consider self intersections`, the redrawn parts of the overcrossing line do not maintain the style: for example, a thick line redraws as thin near the crossing, and loses any colour. Is this a bug? Is there a simple workaround?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{knot}[consider self intersections]
    \strand[thick,red] (-1,-1) to (1,1);
    \strand[thick,blue] (1,-1) to  (-1,1);
    \end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Outputs

[image]

Comment: Your MWE doesn't produce that picture.  How are the blue and red colours being applied?

Comment: Quite right @LoopSpace, thanks, included an older version of MWE without colours originally. Now fixed.

Comment: Okay, that's the way I thought you might be doing it and that works for me.  Where are you getting the knots library from?  (ie if you're using TeXLive, which year?)

Comment: I was using TeXLive 2014. Your comment prompted me to update to 2016, and now the output is as expected!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by updating